# How to mock an out parameter with It.IsAny<> with Moq?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, out

I would like to verify that a method is only called once.

```
mock.Verify(x => x.Method("String", out It.IsAny<StringBuilder>()), Times.Once);
```

I don't care about the second parameter, it could be anything.

I get the following error message because of the `out` parameter:

> 'out' argument must be an assignable variable, field or array element

Answer (score 3):

You can verify for Any by using `It.Ref<StringBuilder>.IsAny`. In your case the solution would be the following:

```
mock.Verify(x => x.Method("String", out It.Ref<StringBuilder>.IsAny), Times.Once);
```

This function was added in [Moq 4.8.0-rc1](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#480-rc1-2017-12-08)

Answer (score 1):

Try following the error message instructions and putting the *out* parameter in a variable.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
mock.Verify(x => x.Method("String", out builder), Times.Once);
```

Here is a full example that passes when tested.

```
[TestClass]
public class ExampleTest {
    public interface IInterface {
        void Method(string p, out StringBuilder builder);
    }

    public class MyClass {
        private IInterface p;

        public MyClass(IInterface p) {
            this.p = p;
        }

        public void Act() {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            p.Method("String", out builder);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Ignore_Out() {
        //Arrange
        var mock = new Mock<IInterface>();
        var sut = new MyClass(mock.Object);

        //Act
        sut.Act();

        //Assert
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        mock.Verify(x => x.Method("String", out builder), Times.Once);
    }
}
```